# How to add vertical scroll bar to one div only without specifying height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I **add a scroll bar to a div when needed but without specifying any height** either for the div itself or for a container that this div must be in?

The div is the very botton element on the page and I want user to be able to resize the browser window. So the scroll bar would appear when the "data" that dynamically add to the div reaches the botton of the page.

My page got contains only one table and second row of the table is below code.

```
<table border="0">
 <tr>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="$('#info').text('')" > clear info area </button></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="tr_info">
    <td><div id='info'></div></td>  
 </tr>
</table>
```

I tried `overflow-y: scroll;` to the div but it added scroll bar to the whole window not the div.

Comment: Your page has only this table?

Comment: I have added javascript and jquery tags assuming that there can be no pure css solution.

Comment: @sabithpocker: basically yes :-) but the code I posted is in the second row of the main table.

Comment: I assume what you want is to share available window height between elements so that everything fits in, if there is not enough space put a sroll bar on "tr_info". Is it what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RSh9H/2/show/

Corrected Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RSh9H/8/show/

jQuery:

```
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
var heightOfWindow = $(window).height();
var totalHeightOfContents = $(document).height();
    if(heightOfWindow <= totalHeightOfContents){
        var heightExcludingInfo = $('table#main').height() - $('#info').height();
        var availableHeightForInfo = heightOfWindow - heightExcludingInfo;
        $('#info').height(availableHeightForInfo);
    }
    else{
        $('#info').css({height:'auto'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Please correct the condition to (heightOfWindow <= totalHeightOfContents) it should be <=

Comment: Works as desired. Thank you so much. :-)

Comment: Could you please explain what `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` does? I didn't use it from the from the beginning and I got second scroll bar for the whole window - it scrolled just few pixels though. Using `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` fixed that. Is `html, body { height: 100%; }` necessary to be used? I removed it and everything seems to be working ok.

Comment: Those `css` is not actually written by me, I forked some other fidle and it came with it. `*{margin:0}` sets zero margin for all elements in document. The `body` has a default margin, you can reset it this way or `body{margin:0}`, that was causing the scrollbar. `html, body { height: 100%; }` is not exactly required in the jQuery solution, it is useful for pure `css` solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
div { height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/xMdPA/

*Less text:* http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/xMdPA/1/

You can also get the text to stay at the bottom of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/xMdPA/2/

Comment: +1 This is correct, but it is difficult to see from your demo (the scroll bar looks like it could be part of JSFiddle). I find setting the height to a small fixed value makes it more obvious: http://jsfiddle.net/xMdPA/3/

Comment: I want the scroll bar to be only inside the red area. So only the red area scrolls. The rest would stay static. http://jsfiddle.net/radek/RSh9H/1/

Comment: Note that the scrollbar _is_ only applied to the red area.

Answer (score 1):

going off @zenkaty 's post,

in the style for that element, put `overflow-y:auto`, this way when it has an overflow it will show a scroller, but if not it will have no scrollbar.

(as opposed to `overflow-y:scroll` which will *always* show a scroll bar.

**Edit:**

As Sabithpocker pointed out, if you have no height, as far as I know, the table will expand to show all text if there is too much. If you set a height, *then* you can use `overflow-y:auto`. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/rZV5u/ for example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you set a height, the default behaviour is overflow:auto :) So there is no need to specify I guess.

Comment: Hahah, yes, that is true. So is the question at hand here, How can we have an auto scroller with no height?!? I don't think that's possible. Perhaps put a max-height instead?

Comment: I guess there is no pure css solution w.r.t the given info. He probably needs some javascript on window resize event.

Comment: I want something like that http://jsfiddle.net/radek/RSh9H/1/ but to be able to scroll only inside the red area. The rest would stay static.

Comment: @Radek, if your #info div is 100% height, there will not be no overflow depending on its container. in your jsfiddle it will be 100% of the whole window -> no overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this on your div - if you add it to the body/html, then the whole window will scroll, obviously.

```
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: He wants to add it "when needed", not at all times.